# How to recalculate a lerp percentage value, so that it returns the same value, even when the max lerp value is adjusted?

Tags: interpolation

I currently have a lerp function, which is 
$$
y = p \cdot x_2 + (1 - p) \cdot x_1,
$$ 
where

- $x_1$ is the min lerp value,
- $x_2$ is the max lerp value,
- $p$ is the percentage to lerp between $x_1$ and $x_2$, in a $0.0$ to $1.0$ format, and
- $y$ is the result of the lerp function.

I was wondering if, by adjusting $x_2$, do there exists a specific formula I could use to recalculate $p$, so that it would output the same result, even with the new $x_2$ value? Is there also a formula I can use for if $x_1$ is adjusted?

I'm sorry if the question is not very easy to understand, if you would like me to clarify anything, please just ask me.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(a,b,t)=tb+a(1-t)$. Then, we are looking for a value $t_2$ such that $f(a,b_1,t_1)=f(a,b_2,t_2)$ where $a$ represents the source value, $b_1$ represents the destination value, $t_1$ represents the interpolation factor, and $b_2$ and $t_2$ represent the new source and interplation factor respectively. If we substitute and rearrange:
$$
\begin{align*}
f(a,b_1,t_1)&=f(a,b_2,t_2);\\
t_1b_1+a(1-t_1)&=t_2b_2+a(1-t_2);\\
t_1(b_1-a)&=t_2(b_2-a);\\
t_2&=\boxed{\frac{t_1(b_1-a)}{b_2-a}},
\end{align*}
$$
which is the formula for the interpolation percentage such that the interpolated value stays the same.

Comment: Hey Shon Verch, thanks for taking the time to try and help me. Unfortunately, that formula didnt return back the same interpolated value, however, using the function **t2 = (t1 * (a - b1)) / (a - b2)** did return back the right lerp value. I will mark the answer as right so people can check the answer and the comment and use what they need to, thank you!

Comment: Yes, my bad. I forgot the initial value terms.